# We have the "record" tag, would a tag for "firsts" or "how many" question be helpful to make these answers grouped and easy to find?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, interesting-tags

The [record](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record) tag currently has **127** questions, and this makes all the valuable answers about space records (most, smallest, etc.) easily accessible to future readers.

We also have classes of questions "What was the first (or earliest)...?" and "...last...?" as well as "How many...?" questions.

I wonder if they should be either added to the [record](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record) tag<sup>1</sup> or to a new tag that serves to help group these answers? First (earliest) and last are sort-of like records, though they can't be broken. (However they can be *corrected*). Some "How many...?" questions can have permanent answers, but for other's things may continue to change over time.

There are plenty of all of those kinds of questions so in this case adding lists of them does not seem helpful.

---

<sup>1</sup>as I have done (as an experiment) on [How many bubble levels have been used in space? Were any of them used some place besides the Moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54268/12102)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am in favor of a `firsts` tag.  The `records` tag should mean the greatest or smallest of a number (i.e. different from `firsts`).  However, it would involve a considerable amount of re-tagging.

There seem to be too many questions for a `how-many` tag, so I am opposed to that.

Comment: [I'm up for it](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/79820)! One does it in "bursts" say 10 or 20 questions at a time, to minimize impact on the active queue.

Comment: @uhoh: Yeah, I wish that retags had their own tab, to avoid polluting the active question tab.

Comment: Which "this" are you most in favor of? "I wonder if they should be **either** added to the record tag **or** to a new tag that serves to help group these answers?"

Comment: @uhoh: Sorry, I've clarified my meta answer.

Comment: opposed to 'how-many' because *too many?* Is it because of the re-tagging loading the active queue?

Comment: No, rather because maybe 1/4 of our questions are a how-many.  It becomes so common that it is useless.

Comment: I think the 1/4 figure is way high but thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Searching questions for the two phrase [how many](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22how+many%22+is%3Aquestion) appearing anywhere in the post returns only 386/15,864 = 2.4%. Compare that to questions tagged `orbital-mechanics` at 1,443/15,864 = 9.1%

Comment: I still don't understand the "too many questions" view (see my previous comments)

Comment: I've added a `spaceflight-firsts` to the currently unanswered questin [Which launch was the first to use a dogleg maneuver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27651/12102) Let's see what happens.

Comment: I've now gone ahead and added `spaceflight-firsts` to a block of 20 questions. I'll wait a week or so and do another. Wherever `record` was used I've removed it; there shouldn't be any overlap. I've also added usage guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I've now gone ahead and added [spaceflight-firsts](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spaceflight-firsts) to an additional block of 20 questions.

I'll wait a week or so between sessions and do between 10 and 20 questions each time. Wherever [record](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/record) was used as a proxy for a first I've removed it; there shouldn't be any overlap.

- `[record] "first" = https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brecord%5D+%22first%22`

I've also added usage guidance.

> First or earliest instances of a notable event, implementation, or technological achievement related to spaceflight. Use the record tag instead for questions of the class fastest, smallest etc. as these records can be set and broken while firsts never change (in principle)